# Does ChannelReader<T>.ReadAllAsync return a static or dynamic enumeration?

Tags: .net-core, task-parallel-library

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync?view=netcore-3.1) for this method simply says:

> Creates an IAsyncEnumerable that enables reading all of the data
>   from the channel.

Does the enumerable returned represent a snapshot of the Channel at the time of calling, or is it a 'live' view of the Channel that will behave correctly if items are added/removed by other actors while I am enumerating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/ChannelReader.netcoreapp.cs) it enumerates the live channel, not a snapshot.

Of course, inherited classes that override this behavior.  You need to examine your specific instance.

Comment: That's neat, so you can actually enumerate over data that hasn't even arrived yet - the enumerator will return an incoming item as it arrives. Sort of like `BlockingCollection.Take` - does this mean you can simply obtain an enumerator instead of using `ChannelReader` methods to continually consume items?

Comment: This is what the implementation I referenced suggests.  You can just await on the enumerator and live happily ever after :-)